# Python, List of lists of raw inputs

Tags: python, list, grid

I am trying to make this code accept some raw inputs (which are strings) and make an array. Instead, it just gives me 1 long list, of all my inputs. The dimensions of the array are supposed to be h by the length of each string (which is constant). I have called the array grid.

```
import sys
import math

def print_it(grid):
    for lst in grid:
        print lst
#############################
h = int(raw_input())
t = raw_input()
for i in xrange(h):
    grid=[]
    row = list(raw_input())
    grid.append([row])
print_it(grid)
```

Comment: Each iteration of the loop recreates your grid. Also, you're reading the raw input and turning it into a list of one element, and then appending that to the grid and putting it in a list again? Variable t is also not being used. I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish. Further clarification would help.

Comment: At the risk of being pedantic, you should know that you are not working with an array, but with a `list`, which does not have dimensions, although they can be nested arbitrarily.

Comment: Ah, thank you all for the insight.

Answer (score 0):

You are resetting `grid` to `[]` each time in the loop. So previous values are lost.

Change it to something like this

```
grid=[]
for i in xrange(h):
    row = list(raw_input())
    grid.append([row])
```

Comment: Omg i can't believe i didn't notice that, thank you.